# Complex Analysis Integration and Differentiation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

After learning about differentiation and integration for complex functions. I am curios about how exactly it can be visualized. Though its 4-Dimensional there are complex function plots using color but haven't seen any such visualization for differentiation and integration. Was wondering if anyone else has come across a visual for differentiation and integration for complex functions.

Thanks,

Comment: Somehow related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWTo2Gk5iU0 (see the part where it talks about the world being 3D)